# How to read a file with a number on each line java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring controller that consumes a `multipart/form-data` type of request. The user will upload a file that contains a number on each line. Each line will be separated with a new line.. e.g.:

```
12314
3434234
324545
```

I currently have the following but not sure if it's efficient:

```
void readFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    List<String> listOfClientId = new ArrayList<>();
    String currentNumber = "";

    if(!file.isEmpty()){

        InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();

        int i = 0;
        while( (i=stream.read()) != -1 ) {

            if( (char) i != '\n'){
                currentNumber = currentNumber + (char) i;
            } else {
                listOfClientId.add(currentNumber);
                currentNumber = "";
            }
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Malformed filed.");
    }
    for(String s : listOfClientId){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `BufferedReader` like so :

```
List<String> collect;
try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
    collect = buffer.lines()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

If you want to get List of Numbers instead of String then you can use :

```
List<Double> collect;
try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
    collect = buffer.lines()
            .map(Double::valueOf) // convert each line(String) to a Double or Integer, it depends on the size of your Numbers
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BufferedReader` to read all the lines of the file:

```
List<String> listOfClientId = new ArrayList<>();
if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
        String number;
        while ((number = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            listOfClientId.add(number);
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Malformed filed.");
}
```

If you are using Java 8 or higher you can use Java Streams with `reader.lines()` and `map()` or `filter()` the values.